# Jquery setTimout method trigger on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a system in which there is time for each question. For now its 10 seconds. If a student doesn't mark the answer in that time, that question will be replaced with the next one. If he marks the answer, it will take him to the next question imidiatly. 
I am using jquery's setTimeout method for the first situation and it is working fine. For the second part, I am unable make a solution. In that situation, I am thinking using a .change function on a radio button. My question is how will be possible for me to show the next question and hide the current on change and keep the time interval for that question same too. Time and number of questions are random actually.
Can anyone help please?

This is what I have done:

```
$('.main_list').children().hide();
var q_count = $('.main_list').children().length;
$('.main_list').children('.show-questions1').show();
//timerHere();
// time here and countdown are timers that should also be updated when    //questions are changed.
//countdown(10, '#qtime');
setInterval(function() {
    $('.main_list').children('.show-questions1').hide(500);
}, 60000);
var i = 2;


    var et = setInterval(function(){
        if(i>2){
            $('.main_list').children().hide();
        }

        $('.main_list').children('.show-questions'+i).show(400);
        //timerHere();
        //countdown(10, '#qtime');
        i= i+1;

        if(i>q_count){

            clearInterval(et);
        }
    },60000);


    $('.check_question').on('change', function(e) {

        var f = $(this).parentsUntil('.options').closest('div').parent().closest('div').attr('class');
        if ($('.'+f).next('div').length)
        {
            $('.'+f).hide(400);
            $('.'+f).next().show(500);
            //timerHere();
            //countdown(10, '#qtime');
            i=i+1;
        } else {
            clearInterval(et);
            $('.hide').removeClass('hide');
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: maybe next time add some code so we can see and give you an example

Comment: "jquery's setTimeout" — jQuery doesn't have a `setTimeout` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clearTimeout` javascript function to cancel the pending timer event.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

```
var timeout;

function ChangeQuestion() {
  // hide current question

  // show next question

  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(ChangeQuestion, 10000);
}
```

Call `ChangeQuestion` on radiobutton `click`.

Comment: That is not helpful in my situation.

Comment: this is what you should be using

Comment: Can you please describe how can i use it in my scenario?

Answer (score 1):

see this link 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout

and next code.. i hope this code helpful for you

```js
var app = {
  questionIndex: 0,
  question: [
    "a","b","c","d"
  ],
  timer: null,
  delayTime: 10000,
  start: function(){
    document.write("start exam...<br/>");
    setTimeout((function(){
      this.printQuestion();
    }).bind(this), this.delayTime);
  },
  printQuestion: function(){
    var _this = this;

    document.write("question " + this.questionIndex + ": " +
    this.question[this.questionIndex] +
    "<br/>" +
    "<button type='button' onclick='app.answer(" + this.questionIndex + ")'>answer</button>" +
    "<br/>");

    if(this.question.length-1 > this.questionIndex){
      this.timer = setTimeout(function(){
          _this.questionIndex++;
          _this.printQuestion();
      }, this.delayTime);
    }else{
      alert("end exam");
    }
  },
  answer: function(idx){
    if(this.timer) clearTimeout(this.timer);

    if(this.question.length-1 > this.questionIndex){
      this.questionIndex++;
      this.printQuestion();
    }else{
      alert("end exam");
    }
  }
};

$(document.body).ready(function(){
  app.start();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well @thomas this is hell of a logic and thanks for your time. But I don't think this is going to solve my problem. I am going to explain it you a bit more.